# CDK Deploy results in a "Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0"

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

Im trying to deploy a super simple CDK stack With just a SQS queue but it throws the error

```
Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.deserializeStructure (/home/ally/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/serialize.ts:19:17)
    at CloudFormationStack.template (/home/ally/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/api/util/cloudformation.ts:70:50)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (/home/ally/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/lib/cdk-toolkit.ts:157:33)
    at initCommandLine (/home/ally/.nvm/versions/node/v14.16.0/lib/node_modules/aws-cdk/bin/cdk.ts:207:9)
```

`cdk --version 1.91.0 (build 0f728ce)`

`node --version v14.16.0`

any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: What's the json?

Comment: I'm guessing its the cloudformation, But I linted it, and it's valid JSON, I can also deploy the cloudformation through the console...

Comment: Can you add you cdk class code ?

Comment: Sorry @BaluVyamajala, New to CDK what is "cdk class code"?

Comment: I meant your code to create SQS queue. Can you add your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end turns out there was an existing cloudformation stack with the same name, I changed the name of my CDK stack and deployed without error